# Acute vowels - Problems with execute mysql files in bat

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have a `.bat` file that executes MySQL files, only `UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries. In one of them I have an update like:

```
Update tabla1 set field_1 = 'abc' where field_2 like '%í%'
```

In this query the process doesn't execute the update. I don't know why. Im sure it is about the acute, the other statements without acutes execute well. And there is no error messages.

I tried by changing the SQL file encoding, nothing changed.

Comment: and where is the acute? but system and oem codepage may differ. try doing a chcp 1252 in batch file prior to sending strings that may be using acutes, or send more details about the real batch and/or sql statement

Comment: You need to make sure that you're using the same charset and collation *everywhere*. Eg: that `í` is a 2-byte UTF8 sequence, but if your collation is an ISO8859 variant like latin1 it's not likely to match.

Comment: How can i see the collation of the sql file? I think the problem will be there

Comment: When i execute the sql file with programs, like SQLYOG, it works good. When i use MySQL commands dont